# Login From Shared Layout as a Partial View or View Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a sign-in option placed in the shared layout header. The goal is that user clicks on sign-in fills credentials and click the button, info will be saved in the session, the page will be refreshed and instead of sign-in, user profile icon etc will be shown.

I have placed HTML/razor code for Sign-In form and profile icon both in separate text files. And Created partial view with this code

```
<ul class="auth__nav">
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.FormToShow)
```

A Partial View load I want to check my session variables if they have values then get profile file code else login form code, but this action is not called

```
public PartialViewResult _SignIn()
    {
        string vFormtoShow = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username")))
        {
            vFormtoShow = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("LogOutForm.txt");
        }
        else vFormtoShow = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("SignInForm.txt");

        ViewBag.FormToShow = vFormtoShow;

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.txt` files, you can use (nested) partials for that.

You can have a `_LogOutForm.cshtml` file and a `_SignInForm.cshtml` file in `Views/Shared`.

Then, you would have a `_UserAuth.cshtml` partial in the same folder:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username"))) 
{
    <partial name="_LogOutForm"/>
}
else
{
    <partial name="_SignInForm"/>
}
```

The `<partial>` tag helper renders a partial view by its name (without the extension).

I suggest you try out [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity), which is a full blown library for users and authentication.